# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) when deleteRows(at: [IndexPath])

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm developing an app which has a main tableview in home screen. When I tap on a certain type of cell of the tableview, I do a little animation and then I delete the cell. I tried the behaviour on all simulator. Only on 4,7" and 5,5" I get a crash when I try to delete a certain row, systematically. I can't understand the error, since Xcode only says: **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)**

This is my code:

```
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        let incomingReminderTableViewCell = cell as! IncomingReminderTableViewCell
        self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        incomingReminderTableViewCell.completeReminderAt(indexPath: indexPath) { (indexPath) in
            let selectedReminder = self.incomingReminders.reversed()[indexPath.row-1]
            if CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.delete(selectedReminder) {
                UserNotificationManager.decreaseBadge()
                UserNotificationManager.deleteNotificationsWith(identifiers: [selectedReminder.idNotification])
                self.incomingReminders = self.incomingReminders.reversed()
                self.incomingReminders.remove(at: indexPath.row-1)
                self.incomingReminders = self.incomingReminders.reversed()

                if self.incomingReminders.isEmpty {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                        incomingReminderTableViewCell.alpha = 0.0
                    }, completion: { (disappeared) in
                        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade )
                        self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    })
                } else {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                        incomingReminderTableViewCell.alpha = 0.0
                    }, completion: { (disappeared) in
                        self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right) // HERE THE CRASH
                        self.incomingReminders = CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.getIncomingReminders()
                        if self.incomingReminders.count == 5 {
                            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
                                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.incomingReminders.count, section: 0)], with: .fade)
                                timer.invalidate()
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            } else {
                self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        }
```

When app crash I have indexPath = (row: 3, section: 0), that is right. DataSource has been correctly updated, before deleteRows I have two element in the array and the data in the tableview start at indexPath = (row: 1, section: 0). Can't find a solution.

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on that line/print the object just before the call and make sure your 'tableView' is actually a UITableView

Comment: I did it and it's ok. But I discovered something else: if I scroll a little the tableview before make it crash, crash doesn't happen. I enabled Zombies objects in debugging and I get this message in console: -[UIImageView retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7ffbb0918c70. I think is a problem of cells reuse: I'm pointing on an element of the cell (imageview) that has been deallocated because the row of it doesn't exists anymore. But I can't figure out how to solve it... Isn't enough to call tableView.deleteRows to update tableView after have updated dataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so convinced, but I've solved in this way:

```
tableView.performBatchUpdates({
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
}, completion: { (deleted) in
    tableView.reloadData()

    self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.incomingReminders = CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.getIncomingReminders()

    if self.incomingReminders.count == 5 {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.incomingReminders.count, section: 0)], with: .fade)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
            timer.invalidate()
        })
    }
 })
```

The problem is after deleted a certain number of rows in tableview, it remained dirty. In fact, deleting a bunch of rows, scrolling, and then continuing to delete, crash didn't happen. I needed to reload data. I put

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
```

as a batch update. And in completion block I called the reload, with other things. All seems ok for now. Hope this can be useful for someone.